# Why For-loop in python did not work in this case

Tags: python, for-loop

I wanna plus each variable (in list) with 1, then I found 2 ways (I code on Jupyter lab).
The 1st one is oke but I don't know why the 2nd one couldn't work. Could anyone explain to me what's wrong with 2nd way please? I would really like to know what computer'd done in case of 2nd method that make the result still the same? Many thanksss

1st method:

```
list_1 = [1,2,3]

[i+1 for i in list_1]

list_1
```

--> results: [2,3,4]

---

2nd method:

```
list_1 = [1,2,3]

for i in list_1:

    i+1

list_1
```

--> results: [1,2,3]

Comment: Please add ``` on the line above and below your code to make it more readable and preserve indentation. (The symbol below the ~ key, not an apostrophe.)

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you, then I understand that when i wrote "i+1" , the computer only calculate it and stored on RAM without assigning these value to any variable, rignt? then i have to create list_2 and used append to store these value?

Comment: *Neither* method actually modifies the input list (assuming what you posted here is what you are actually running). You may be getting confused by the interpreter printing the result of the list comprehension. Look at the output more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding. Neither method modifies the input list. You may be confused by the interpreter showing you the result of the list comprehension, but that is *not* stored back to the variable, because you did not assign it. If you look at the interpreter output more carefully, you will see that the input list is unmodified in both cases:

```
>>> list_1 = [1,2,3]
>>> [i+1 for i in list_1]
[2, 3, 4]
>>> list_1
[1, 2, 3]

>>> list_2 = [1,2,3]
>>> for i in list_2:
...     i+1
... 
2
3
4
>>> list_2
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you do want to save the new values to the list variable, you can assign the result of the list comprehension to the variable:

```
>>> list_1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list_1 = [i+1 for i in list_1]
>>> list_1
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Oh this answer gave the root understanding for me! many thanks. Voted!

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you create new values, that are saved in a new list, then assigned to `list_1` so keep these new values

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_1 = [i + 1 for i in list_1]
print(list_1)  # [2, 3, 4]
```

In the second case `i+1` does nothing, it add one, but you don't save it anywhere, to fix that, you may re-assign to the correct index in the list, with basic iteration, or with `enumerate`

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
for idx in range(len(list_1)):
    list_1[idx] += 1


list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
for idx, value in enumerate(list_1):
    list_1[idx] = value + 1
```

Comment: The OP's first method never actually assigns back to `list_1` though. It doesn't "work" (as posted); they are misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

The loop still works, your result didn't correct because you miss-understand the code.

the variable `i` just a temp variable was copied from the list, so you just assign the variable `i`, not assign the list so the list didn't change value.

the solution is:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
for idx, value in enumerate(list_1):
    list_1[idx] = value + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the logic of the 2nd one is not correct. You are simply increasing the value inside the list but are not assigning those values to the list.

the correct logic would be

```
list_1 = [1,2,3]
count=0
for i in list_1:

    count=count+1
    list_1[count-1]= i+1

list_1
```

FYI.. the 1st logic is also not correct and it never works as well.